# Dockerization of an RShiny application with Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml : where is my app?

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I have an R Shiny application that I would like to dockerize to deploy on my own server.

To test it I first deploy on my own machine. I am using Windows.

Here is the folder of my application :
[image]

In the folder *application* there is the R Shiny code : app.R
In the folder *sources* there are the dataframes.

My *Dockerfile* is the following :

```
FROM rocker/shiny:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libsodium-dev

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny',...))"

EXPOSE 3838
```

My *docker-compose.yaml* is the following :

```
version: "3"

services:
  shiny:  
    container_name: rshiny
    image: rshiny:v1
    ports:
      - 80:3838
    volumes:
      - /home/shiny/application:/application
      - /home/shiny/sources:/sources
```

Then, I use the following code lines on my cmd to dockerize my application :

```
docker build -t rshiny:v1 .
docker-compose up
```

But then when I go on my localhost (or localhost:80) I have this page :
[image]

Where is my application ? I don't find it...

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: As the folder containing `app.R` is called `application` and you have added this to your `docker-compose.yaml`, if the folder has successfully been shared with the container, your app should be at `http://localhost/application/`

Comment: Dear @SamR thank you for your message. No it is not on http://localhost/application/

Comment: The default app is running from `/srv/shiny-server/`. You'll probably need a symbolic link to the application folder in there. It's complicated - I found this walkthrough for shiny servers useful https://www.charlesbordet.com/en/guide-shiny-aws/#3-how-to-configure-shiny-server

Comment: To add to the useful comment on how to debug by @AndyBaxter, you will need to run these commands inside your docker container. You can enter it by running in a terminal `docker exec -it [container_name] bash`, or if you need to be root, `docker exec -itu root [container_name] bash`.

Comment: I don't understand exactly but I cannot use my terminal because the container is running :

https://i.imgur.com/dQOOMDm.jpeg

Comment: Ok so with ```docker-compose up -d``` I can use my terminal while the container is running

Comment: Maybe this is a problem of port ?